# Requestqueue and json

Tags: java, android, json

I have problem with my RequeatQueue,

```
RequestQueue requestQueue=Volly.newRequestQueue(this);
```

A red line comes under "this" and the following error appears:

> newRequestQueue(android.content.Context)in 'com.android.Volly.toolbox.Volly' can not be applief to '(com.example.world.tes1.view.activity.weatherSampleActivity)'

Comment: Please copy the exact warning that Android Studio gives you.

Comment: Please provide more details, or see this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795970/cant-make-a-new-newrequestqueue-in-volley-android

Comment: @regina_fallangi newRequestQueue(android.content.Context)in 'com.android.Volly.toolbox.Volly' can not be applief to '(com.example.world.tes1.view.activity.weatherSampleActivity)'

Comment: @XavierBrt  newRequestQueue(android.content.Context)in 'com.android.Volly.toolbox.Volly' can not be applief to '(com.example.world.tes1.view.activity.weatherSampleActivity)'

Comment: @XavierBrt sorry i did not get it

Comment: The link I gave you seems to be a similar question. Maybe it will answer your question.
When you add more info, add it in your original question, by editing it, not in the comments zone

Comment: @regina_fallangi  thanks riends it solved.very  simple

Comment: @XavierBrt thanks it solved.very simple

Comment: There is no need to answer every person.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Requestqueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(SampleActivity.this);
```